# 4px of extra space coming from nowhere

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a UL and inside of that UL I have an image which I have set in css to be 200px wide. However, when it is rendered on a web page, there is an extra 4px to the right of the image. Chrome's inspect element shows that for some reason the UL itself is 204px. I can fix this by setting the UL to width:200px, however that doesn't work in the long run because I need to add padding to the image and if I do that the image gets offset.

Here's all the relevant CSS:

```
#imagesUl {
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.2);
margin-left:40px;
margin-top:20px;
height:220px;
}
#imagesUl h1{
padding-top:0px;
margin:0px;
font-weight:bold;
display:inline-block;
color: #515050;
}
#imagesUl img {
width:200px;
padding:0px;
}
```

And a picture of it in chrome (you can see the extra 4px on the right of the image)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

display:inline-block has a problem with adding 4px of extra space

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had this markup:

```
<p><img src="img1.jpg" />
<img src="img2.jpg" /></p>
```

You would expect to see a gap between these two images because there is a line break between them. This is interpreted as horizontal white space. The same thing is happening with your `<ul>` elements. If you remove the horizontal white space between them, the problem will go away.

In other words change this:

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

to this:

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
</ul><ul>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```